# Sort by entity's method with KNP pagination

Tags: symfony, sorting, knppaginator

I have entity with method getItemsAmount, that fetches all Item entities related to my parent entity, counts them and returns result as regular integer.

Then I create table for parent entity with "Items Amount" column.

Now when i try to configure KNP pagination to sort by "itemsAmount" property of parent entity, I do get exception:

```
There is no such field [itemsAmount] in the given Query component, aliased by [a]
```

Thats obvious - I do not have such a property, I calculate it with my Entity class after its fetched.

Is there possibility to make KNP pagination sort such things ?

Comment: Check the same issue with its solution at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120352/sorting-not-working-in-knp-paginator

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? I have the same issue and don't think that the one mentioned by Rupal is exactly the same.

Comment: Kevlar - no, I dont even remember what was it about - it was so long ago... If I understand myself correctly - I was up to sort with KNP pagination by method call instead of database column. If this is what you want than I have bad news: it probably wont work, KNP operated on query builder, that has to build SQL query before it is sent to the DB - so you can only operate on your DB columns.